# Наследование в javascript с использованием Object.setPrototypeOf

Tags: javascript

Вопрос один возник, может кто подсказать? 
Пробую наследовать через Object.setPrototypeOf.

```
let obj = {
agr1: true,
arg2: function () {
return true
}

function FormatError (message) {
  this.name = "FormatError"
};
```

`Object.setPrototypeOf(FormatError.prototype, obj.prototype)` - не работает, только так `FormatError.prototype =  obj`

А если таким образом наследовать от SyntaxError например то работает `Object.setPrototypeOf(FormatError.prototype, SyntaxError.prototype)`, а с `FormatError.prototype =  SyntaxError` - проблемы

Comment: что ты понимаешь под наследованием в данном случае? почему ты решил что не работает?

Comment: Потому что на строке - ```Object.setPrototypeOf(FormatError.prototype, obj.prototype) ``` Выдает ошибку - ```Uncaught TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at Function.setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)``` Под наследованием понимаю возможность объекта созданного с помощью FormatError использовать свойства и методы объекта obj.

Answer (score 0):

Если выполнить `console.log(obj.prototype)` можно увидеть, что выведется `undefined`. Так как в объекте `obj` нет свойства с именем `prototype`.

Чтобы получить прототип объекта, нужно воспользоваться функцией [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

Однако в этом случае это не поможет, так как поля и методы находятся непосредственно в объекте `obj`, а не его прототипе.

Поэтому решением может быть только присваивание самого объекта.